# Nmap scan a network range with subnet raises PortScannerError

Tags: python, nmap

I'm trying to scan a nmap with the 192.168.10.1/24 network, using Python 3.9.2, Nmap 7.80 and [`python-nmap`](https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/) 0.7.1

Code:

```
import nmap
nm = nmap.PortScanner()

result = nm.scan(hosts = '192.168.10.1/24')
print(result)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/nmap/nmap.py", line 369, in analyse_nmap_xml_scan
    dom = ET.fromstring(self._nmap_last_output)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1348, in XML
    return parser.close()
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 7, column 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fypgroup02/Documents/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    result = nm.scan(hosts = '192.168.10.1/24')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/nmap/nmap.py", line 306, in scan
    return self.analyse_nmap_xml_scan(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/nmap/nmap.py", line 372, in analyse_nmap_xml_scan
    raise PortScannerError(nmap_err)
nmap.nmap.PortScannerError: "nmap: Target.cc:503: void Target::stopTimeOutClock(const timeval*): Assertion `htn.toclock_running == true' failed.\n"
```

I have tried to scan 192.168.10.1-10, it works, but why is 192.168.10.1/24 not working?

Comment: Which `nmap` library are you using? Do you have reasons to assume it supports CIDR notation?

Comment: python-nmap 0.7.1

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Going forward, please [edit] your question to update it.